# Jenkins Parallel Pipeline Race Condition Blocking all Builds

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Any clues on why parallel pipeline would cause a race condition?

This used to work where the job would schedule tasks on all nodes and they'd execute once busy nodes freed up.

After upgrading, If jenkins maintenance job cannot execute on all nodes at first execution it creates race condition blocking jenkins from executing anything even though nodes are free to do so.

```
@NonCPS
List <String> getOnlineNodeNames() {
  List <String> nodeNames = []
  def allNodes = Jenkins.getInstance().getNodes()
  for (int i =0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) {
   Slave node = allNodes[i]

   if (node.getComputer().isOnline()) {  
    nodeNames.add(node.name.toString())
   }
  }
  return nodeNames
}


stage name: "Prepare", concurrency: 1
List<String> nodeList = getOnlineNodeNames()

branches = [:]
stage name: "Build", concurrency: 1
for (int i =0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
  String nodeName = nodeList[i]
  if(nodeName.contains("win")) {
    branches[nodeName] = { node(nodeName) { 
    bat '''echo On windows Node'''
   } 
  }
  } else {
    branches[nodeName] = { node(nodeName) { 
         sh '''echo on linux node'''
       } 
    }
  }
}
parallel branches
```